# Android: Modifying adapter content from a background thread

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I've read up quite a bit on the exception thrown while using BaseAdapter, but i can't seem to find an alternative solution:
**Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread**

What i want to achieve is to keep a copy of a message queue in memory, and use this message queue to populate the BaseAdapter for my ListView. The reason im doing this is that the message queue will keep getting messages from a socket even when the ListView is not currently present (for example a chat window).

The problem comes when i have the **Activity** with the **ListView** in foreground, **BaseAdapter** binded to the message queue's data, and a message comes in the socket. Adding the new message into the queue will throw the exception mentioned above. Unless i pre-populate my **BaseAdapter** with the message queue (as in the BaseAdapter having its own message queue) and updating both of them when a new message come in, i can't really find a way around this issue.

I don't really want to double up the effort on keeping those 2 queues up-to-date like this, surely there is a better way of doing this? Send broadcasts around doesn't work either because of the potential delay in the adapter serving a scroll and the notifyDataSetChanged call is made.

Comment: What Adapter are you really using? You do realize that BaseAdapter is abstract right? Also, what exception do you get? You do not mention it.

Comment: Hi, at the moment i'm just creating my own class by extending BaseAdapter, implementing the methods getCount(), getItem(), getItemId() and getView(); The exception is the one stated above: "Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread". Caused by trying to update the adapter's data set from a non-ui thread (in this case, my controller class which holds the message queue). I'm trying to find a way to keep my message queue updated as well as the Activity (if it is in the foreground).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Handler` to modify the "message queue" from the main application thread.

Comment: i was thinking of doing it this way, but that means any messages coming from the network layer will have to be broadcasted for the Activity to pick up. If the Activity is not in the foreground (or in the activity stack), the message will not be processed. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Bundee: "but that means any messages coming from the network layer will have to be broadcasted for the Activity to pick up." -- in principle, you can use a `Handler` in a `Service` for this, though I have not tried it.

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same question until I realized that it has already been asked before. I can confirm that CommonsWare solution works. I used a Handler in my Serivce to modify the content of an Adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. It turns out I was recreating my adapter for new data but the old adapter was still set to the listview and would occasionally cause a crash. So I do something like this when I need to recreate the adapter:

```
//Clear adapter's array
if (!array.isEmpty()) { array.clear(); }
if (adapter != null) { adapter = null; }
setListAdapter(adapter);

//Later code
//array gets repopulated
//adapter gets recreated
setListAdapter(adapter);
```